# Promise catching the results inside the promise structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, angular-promise

Here is my entire code, and what I want to avoid are all the moveAllBank, moveAllReceipt moveAllExpense functions if possible.  The code below works fine, I just wish there was a smarter way of doing it.  Its really hard to understand how the different promises passes data between each other.

```
// 
// Find all bank accounts
// 
var bankModel = require('../models/bankModel');
var bankTable = mongoose.model('bankModel');
var bankArray = [];
var findAllBank = new Promise(
    (resolve, reject) => {
    bankTable.find({}
    ,function(err, data) {
        if (!err) {
            resolve(data);
        } else {
            reject(new Error('findBank ERROR : ' + err));
        }
    });
});
let moveAllBank = function (data) {
    bankArray = data;
    console.log("receiptArray Result: " + JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
};


// 
// Find the RECEIPT for each bank account
// 
var receiptModel = require('../models/receiptModel');
var receiptTable = mongoose.model('receiptModel');
var receiptArray = [];
let findAllReceipts = function (accountArray) {
    return Promise.all(bankArray.map(findReceipts));
};
function findReceipts(account) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        receiptTable.find({account: account._id}, function (err, data) {
            if (!err) {
                console.log("findReceipts Result: " + JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
                resolve(data);
            } else {
                reject(new Error('findReceipts ERROR : ' + err));
            }
        });
    });
}
let moveAllReceipt = function (data) {
    receiptArray = data;
    console.log("receiptArray Result: " + JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
};


// 
// Find the EXPENSE for each bank account
// 
var expenseModel = require('../models/expenseModel');
var expenseTable = mongoose.model('expenseModel');
var expenseArray = [];
let findAllExpense = function (accountArray) {
    console.log("=====EXPENSE====")
    console.log("accountArray Result: " + JSON.stringify(accountArray, null, 4));
    return Promise.all(bankArray.map(findExpense));
};
function findExpense(account) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        expenseTable.find({account: account._id}, function (err, data) {
            if (!err) {
                console.log("findExpense Result: " + JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
                resolve(data);
            } else {
                reject(new Error('findExpense ERROR : ' + err));
            }
        });
    });
}
let moveAllExpense = function (data) {
    expenseArray = data;
    console.log("expenseArray Result: " + JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
};


// 
// Send the result
// 
let sendResult = function (data) {
    res.json({error:false,  "bank":bankArray, "receipt":receiptArray, "expense":expenseArray})
};  


// 
// Run the promises
// 
findAllBank
    .then(moveAllBank)
    .then(findAllReceipt)
    .then(moveAllReceipt)
    .then(findAllExpense)
    .then(moveAllExpense)
    .then(sendResult)
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
        console.log("getbankAccountReport ERR: " + err);
        res.json({error:true,err})
    });
```

Comment: Do you mean `.then(() => res.json`?

Comment: `.then(() =>bankArray)` is that what you mean torazaburo?

Comment: Every then method has the same signature, you need to pass it functions.

Comment: your `then` code should indeed be a function - just use the `data => bankData = data` approach to register an anonymous function inline

Comment: @OvidiuDolha I tried it but get no result.  Even thou the function runs perfectly and actually produce data, there is nothing put into the array with 
 `.then(expenseArray => findAllExpense(bankArray))`

Comment: @torbenrudgaard That would suggest that they *don't* run perfectly fine. Please find a way, and show us, how to actually call the functions (including `findBank()`?) with their expected parameters, then we still can figure out how to collect your results.

Comment: When you have *working* code, and you are asking for a review to improve certain aspects, codereview.stackexchange.com might be a better place.

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
findBank
  .then(bank => findAllReceipts(bank)
    .then(receipt => bank.findAllExpense(bank)
      .then(expense =>
        res.json({error:false, bank, receipt, expense})
      )
    )
  )
  .catch(err => res.json({error:true,err});
```

Or just

```
try {
  const bank = await findBank;
  const receipt = await findAllReceipts(bank);
  const expense = await findAllExpense(bank);
  res.json({error: false, bank, receipt, expense});
} catch(error) {
  res.json({error});
}
```

To use `await`, of course the function must be marked as `async`.

Comment: None of them work - In your first example only the findBank() produce a result, none of the other .then's work.  And in the second example all await give errors at the await function(); `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Comment: @torbenrudgaard You need to make your function `async` for that, and possibly enable the feature in your transpiler. However, the snippets are equivalent, so if one won't work then the other will neither.

Comment: @Bergi I like the promise structure better in this case. But how do you get the result from a promise and how do you send results to the promise?  That is my biggest issue here. I know promises send the result to each other by default, but can you change that and send other things?

Comment: @torbenrudgaard promises send their results to their *callbacks*. Please don't confuse promises for the functions that create them. And what you do with the parameters in your callback functions is entirely your choice.

Comment: @Bergi I read the other post (the one that replaces mine as duplicate) and you give some great examples and information.  You are like the godfather of promises :-))  But im still pretty new to async programming so I still cant understand how I can implement your suggestions.  I updated my question and put all the code and rephrased my question.

Comment: @torbenrudgaard The code in torazaburos answer is exactly what I am suggesting (and the many other ways from the duplicate :D). The only reason this would not work with your `findAllReceipts` and `findAllExpense` functions is that they ignore their `accountArray`  parameter and refer to the global `bankArray` instead. Also I had expected `findBank` to be a function that needed to be called, not a promise - I'll edit this answer

Comment: @Bergi so the only way is (like I do) to make the moveAll functions and make them put data into the arrays?

Comment: @torbenrudgaard No, you don't need those. Change your `findAll*` functions to consider their parameters, and use the code from this answer.